# Spherecasting not hitting where I want it to

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, game-physics

I am sphere casting a 4 unit radius sphere, 2 units in front of the player and bool returns true for a specific interval of far distances; from 5 units in front of the player till max distance (radius + 2 units)

Not sure if this is how the spherecasting is supposed to work but if it is, is it possible to make the bool return true when it detects hits inside the whole sphere?

```
   private void Locking(RaycastHit hit)
    {
        if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 4f, transform.forward, out hit, 2f, lmask, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal))
        {
            Vector3 hitp = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, 0, hit.transform.position.z);
            transform.LookAt(hitp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sphere cast doesn't grab everything inside the sphere. It sends a ray out in a sphere like shape till it first touches something it's looking to detect. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nplcqwq_oJU) that uses gizmo's to show roughly how it works. If you want to have a sphere find out about everything inside it at a given point I recommend using [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) instead.

Comment: i read a lot of documentation and cannot grasp the way physics.overlapsphere works tbh

Comment: It returns all the colliders inside of it as an array. You can then loop through that array to influence other scripts based on that. So for example in your case, you can use a normal raycast to determine if you're looking at something in a certain distance. Then use the raycast info to create a OverlapSphere at the point the raycast hits. From there, look at the array of colliders it returns. If it returns null, empty, or the gameobject using the collider doesn't match a tag you want then you have a miss. Otherwise, use the collider to access the gameobjects and apply results onto them.